# How can I pass a templated class 'this' pointer to member function

Tags: c++

How can I pass a templated class 'this' pointer to a member function of that class i.e.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
....
process(A<T>* a) {};
someOtherFunction() {process(this)};
....
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what your question is. Could you perhaps illustrate how you would do it without templates, for example?

Comment: `this` ia always passed implicitly to non static member functions.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do, since just calling a member function of the same object automatically "passes" `this`. Do you mean you want to call `process` in *another* object of the `A` class? Another object with another `T`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, that show how you want to use the function?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    static void process(A* a) {}
    void someOtherFunction() {process(this)};
}
```

You don't need to specify `T`, and `process` can be `static` since it is explicitly passed `this`.  But you can just let it happen implicitly instead:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    void process() { A* a = this; }
    void someOtherFunction() {process()};
}
```